# Using a SWC's MainTimeline?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

So I have a SWC made from a FLA (published to one), and the only thing in it is an object called MainTimeline. I can't use addChild on this, convert it to MovieClip, etc. What am I supposed to do with "MainTimeline"? Is there a way I can put this in my program?

Comment: What's in your FLA?  SWCs are great for packaging code or library assets like symbols and fonts.

Comment: Please provide more Details. Is "MainTimeLine" an Object in your Library that has AS-Linkage? Or is it just an Object somewhere on the Stage of your FLA?

Comment: Like I said, I just published my fla to a swc and it only had that.

Answer (score 0):

If MainTimeline is a symbol in the your SWC library then you can use it like a symbol in your main fla that you instantiate in your code.

You need to set MainTimeline's ActionScript linkage to "Export for ActionScript", then add the SWC to your main movie in Actionscript Settings dialog in Flash. In your main movie Flash code do something like this:

```
var mt=new MainTimeline();
addChild(mt);
```

to instantiate and display the MainTimeline from the SWC in your main movie.